# Whats the proper way to iterate through an object?

Tags: javascript

I've always used

```
for( x in object ){}
```

but I just came accros

```
for( var x in object){}
```

I know the var matters in regular

```
for( var i=0;i<10;i++){}
```

statements, it bit me once in a recursive function, 
but does it matter when using for x in?...

Comment: do you know what `var` mean ?

Comment: This question is more about what `var` does than how to iterate through an object.

Comment: I'm partial to `Object.keys(obj).forEach( key => ...)` but, you know, ymmv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Re the `var` part:

> Does it matter when using for x in?

***Yes***. It *always* matters to declare your variables. If you don't, and you're using loose mode, you fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). (In strict mode, it's a nice detectable error. Use strict mode.) That will bite you in a recursive function, and in any of a large number of other non-recursive situations.

You don't have to declare it *within* the `for` construct, just make sure you declare it somewhere.

---

#### Re *"Whats the proper way to iterate through an object?"*:

There are several proper ways. [Like Mathletics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098397/whats-the-proper-way-to-iterate-through-an-object/32098502#comment52091383_32098397), I'm partial to using `Object.keys(...).forEach(...)`:

```js
var obj = {
  a: "ay",
  b: "bee",
  c: "see"
};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  snippet.log(key + ": " + obj[key]);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note that `Object.keys` will only look at the object's *own* properties, not the properties of its prototype.

The reason I like it is that it gives me a nice self-contained scope for what I'm doing on each "loop" iteration. If you're worried about the runtime cost of those callbacks, [don't be](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html).

---

But you can also just use a `for in` loop. If you do, you may or may not want to include `hasOwnProperty`, depending on whether you want to visit prototype properties.

```js
var proto = {
  a: "ay (proto)",
  b: "bee (proto)",
  c: "see (proto)",
  d: "dee (proto)"
};
var obj = Object.create(proto);
obj.a = "ay";
obj.b = "bee";
obj.c = "see";

// Includes prototype properties if not shadowed by the object's own
snippet.log("for-in without hasOwnProperty");
var key;
for (key in obj) {
  snippet.log(key + ": " + obj[key]);
}

// Does not include prototype properties
snippet.log("for-in using obj.hasOwnProperty");
for (key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    snippet.log(key + ": " + obj[key]);
  }
}

// If you're feeling paranoid about `obj` having had
// `hasOwnProperty` overridden, you can use it from `Object.prototype`:
snippet.log("for-in using Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty");
for (key in obj) {
  // Does not include prototype properties
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
    snippet.log(key + ": " + obj[key]);
  }
}
// I've never needed to do that in the real world, though
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Just don't use `for-in` on *arrays* without using appropriate safeguards; more about why (and your alternatives) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Comment: Thanks so much, extremely helpful!